# Pick date in google form with selenium

Tags: python, forms, selenium, bots, google-forms

so I try to make a bot using selenium in python and I stuck in date form here the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
website = driver.get("https://forms.gle/VUwbshGuXxDb7NRbA")
time.sleep(1)
tanggal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input").send_keys("12")
```

I already tried using  `click()` and `send_keys()` but it won't work

Comment: We need to see the code to help you further.

Comment: @cruisepandey i just made the code because the real code it wont work(it's the same but different link) and i dont know how it work, i new in this thing

Comment: Please see below.

Comment: @cruisepandey thank you so much for your help and sorry can i ask again how to make the date today (sorry bad english)

Comment: Did you mean to ask how to pass today's date ?

Comment: i want the date to be today so it will automatic change every day

Comment: Please see below the updated code .

Comment: @cruisepandey you are my hero thank you so much mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use **explicit waits**.
2. I could update the date with the help of `JS setAttribute`.
3. Date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Code :

```
from datetime import datetime
today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://forms.gle/VUwbshGuXxDb7NRbA")
time.sleep(1)
date= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")))
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{today_date}')", date)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```